# Hibernate Issue with generated schema when using @LOB and jasypt @Type annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, encryption, jasypt

I am working with the following

```
package org.temp

import org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.jasypt.hibernate4.type.EncryptedStringType;


import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Lob;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;


@TypeDef(
        name="encryptedString",
        typeClass=EncryptedStringType.class,
        parameters= {
                @Parameter(name="encryptorRegisteredName", value="defaultStringEncryptor")
        }
)


@Entity
@Table(name = "MESSAGE")
public class MessageEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "MESSAGE_ID", nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "MESSAGE_ID_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "MESSAGE_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "MESSAGE_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1,
      initialValue = 1)
  private BigInteger messageId;

  @Column(name = "SUBJECT")
  private String subject;

  @Type(type="encryptedString")
  @Lob
  @Column(name = "CONTENT")
  private String content;

...
}
```

the intent is to encrypt the contents so as if anyone is querying the db they won't see the data stored in the Content column. Which all is working fine, however...

Prior to adding the @Type(type="encryptedString")

In the generated schema I got this

```
create table MESSAGE (
    MESSAGE_ID number(19,2) not null,
    CONTENT clob,
    SUBJECT varchar2(255),
    primary key (MESSAGE_ID)
);
```

But when I added the @Type(type="encryptedString")

```
create table MESSAGE (
    MESSAGE_ID number(19,2) not null,
    CONTENT varchar2(255),
    SUBJECT varchar2(255),
    primary key (MESSAGE_ID)
);
```

Using hibernate 4.1.3.Final, jasypt 1.9.2

I've been digging and researching on how to correctly annotate but haven't had any luck

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found a work around for this. Am a little new to Hibernate so missed this option.

Basically Dropped the

```
@lob
```

And updated the following:

```
@Column(name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition = "CLOB")
```

Was going to use "TEXT" for efficiency, but the requirements for the project indicated that the field should be able to hold large amounts of data.